# How to get rid of pytest warnings

Tags: python, pytest

When I run my pytest in pipenv shell I get this:

```sh
 pipenv shell
Loading .env environment variables…
Launching subshell in virtual environment…

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
bash-3.2$  . /Users/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/kittycapital-UOiJxZhy/bin/activate
(kittycapital) bash-3.2$ python -m pytest
============================================================================================================================= test session starts ==============================================================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.7, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/.../kittycapital
plugins: mock-3.1.1
collected 4 items

tests/test_account.py .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  [ 25%]
tests/test_pair.py ..                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    [ 75%]
tests/helpers/test_number_helpers.py .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   [100%]

=============================================================================================================================== warnings summary ===============================================================================================================================
/Users/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/kittycapital-UOiJxZhy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/selectors.py:14
  /Users/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/kittycapital-UOiJxZhy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/selectors.py:14: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3,and in 3.9 it will stop working
    from collections import namedtuple, Mapping

/Users/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/kittycapital-UOiJxZhy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/_collections.py:2
  /Users/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/kittycapital-UOiJxZhy/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/_collections.py:2: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3,and in 3.9 it will stop working
    from collections import Mapping, MutableMapping

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
```

How do I get rid of these warnings?

Comment: I suspect you need to install a newer version of `urllib3`.  Which version do you have installed?

Answer (score 8):

Either upgrade your dependencies to versions that do not trigger warnings, or put this in `pytest.ini` to hide that warning:

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings = ignore:.*Using or importing the ABCs.*is deprecated:DeprecationWarning
```

See https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html#deprecationwarning-and-pendingdeprecationwarning

Or use the `--disable-warnings` flag to hide *all* warnings:

```
python -m pytest --disable-warnings
```

See https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html#disabling-warnings-summary